# OrientDB Studio - Can OrientDB Studio 1.7.8 be used to drop a database?

Tags: orientdb

The Studio documentation page on the orientechnologies.com site states that databases can be dropped using Studio:

```
Select a database from the databases list and click the trash icon. Studio will open a confirmation popup where you have to insert [credentials.]
```

The studio zip file that ships with 1.7.10 is studio-1.7.8.zip.  I've gone through Studio with a number of databases and I haven't seen any Trash icons anywhere.  Am I missing something?

The Studio documentation page states that:

```
This is the new Studio 2.0 Homepage.
```

I thought I saw an Issue stating that database drop capability was added in late August. Is it supported in studio 1.7.8?

I suppose I could try unpacking the studio zip file from the 2.0 M3 distribution.  Has anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Studio 1.7.x does not have such feature.
You can try to take the studio of 2.0 M3 distribution. Not all feature will work
like downloading databases from the cloud and other. But the basic features like dropping db should work.

Never tried that